# How to write LINQ Concat query properly

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core-3.1

The below `LINQ` on `concat` throws an error

> Set operations over different store types are currently unsupported

```
var data = await (_context.tb1.Select(s => new { s.id, cat = s.category }) // cat is either "R" or "O"
                .Concat
                (_context.tb2.Select(s => new { s.id, cat = "C" })) // cat is constant "C" here.
                ).ToListAsync();

public class tb1
    {
        public long id { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(2)] // R - Reimbursement, O - Others
        public string category { get; set; }
    }

public class tb2
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
    
    // Some Other Properties...
    }
```

What I tried?

```
public class tb3
    {
        public long id { get; set; }

        public string cat { get; set; }
    }

var data = await (_context.tb1.Select(s => new tb3 { id =  s.id, cat = s.category }) // cat is either "R" or "O"
                .Concat
                (_context.tb2.Select(s => new tb3 { id = s.id, cat = "C" })) // cat is constant "C" here.
                ).ToListAsync();
```

What is fault in this query? I use `Asp.Net Core 3.1` with `Postgresql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue. Try bringing down the entities locally by forcing materialization:

```
await (_context.tb1.Select(s => new { s.id, cat = s.category }.ToList()) // cat is either "R" or "O"
            .Concat
            (_context.tb2.Select(s => new { s.id, cat = "C" }).ToList()) // cat is constant "C" here.
            ).ToListAsync();
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.pmichaels.net/tag/system-invalidoperationexception-set-operations-over-different-store-types-are-currently-unsupported/).

The alternative is to run the query on the server using a stored procedure.

Comment: I have another few queries like this and that works fine witout adding `.ToList()`. However I just want to get the data from the server with only one round trip.

Comment: @Ramesh: If you read the link I provided, you will see that internally, it still makes two trips to the server so it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining two "collections" of two different type

the first one is an `IQueryable<tb1>` the second is an `IQueryable<tb2>`

you have two solutions:

- introduce an interface/abstract class with common fields and make tb1 and tb2 inerith that
- use `.Cast<object>` or `.Cast<dynamic>` (won't recomend this aproach!)

Comment: also .ToList() could help
have you also tryed .Union instead of Concat?